# How to Build Multiple Android Projects in one go

Tags: java, android, ant, build

I have one Android Project. I created Junit test project for the same. I can build the both projects using ANT script independently. Now, I want to write the script which will call this ANT scripts and build the project. How I can do it ?

I am currently using Windows-Xp, eclipse- Galileo, jdk - 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) task in ant.

You can then write a "binding" build.xml file which calls all of the other "build.xml" files with the appropriate tasks (in whatever appropriate order).

An example (from the manual)

```
<ant antfile="subproject/subbuild.xml" target="compile"/>
```

Which would then call the "compile" target in the `subproject/subbuild.xml` file.